# Combinations of Scrabble letters BINGO

Tags: combinatorics

The holy grail of Scrabble is the BINGO - a word that uses all seven letters of your rack. There is a 50 point bonus for a BINGO! There is a common bit of advice given to Scrabble players – try to leave your rack without repeated letters on it. Let’s see why people care:

I would appreciate feedback on my initial thoughts...

> a) How many "BINGOes" can you make with 7 distinct letters?

$26 \choose 7$

> b) How many "BINGOes" can you make with 7 letters, where two are repeated (such as AABCDEF)

First, choose the repeated letter $26 \choose 1$

Next, choose the remaining 5 letters $25 \choose 5$

The total ways would be $26$ $\times$ $25 \choose 5$

> c) How many "BINGOes" can you make with 7 letters, where there is a triple (such as AAABCDE)

First, choose the triple letter $26 \choose 1$

Next, choose the remaining 4 letters $24 \choose 4$

The total ways would be $26$ $\times$ $24 \choose 4$

Am I on the right track or am I missing pieces?

Comment: You're actually counting the number of ways to have a specific configuration of letters. Not the words you can make with those letters. There are 7! unique "words" that you can make with those letters (assuming they are all distinct... if one letter has multiplicity, choose the k distinct positions (7 choose k)  to place the letters with multiplicity and then multiply by the n-k! other possible combinations of the other letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a), note that you can choose the letters for your word in $\binom{26}{7}$ ways, but you totally forgot that $abel$ and $leab$ are not the same word! You have to multiply by $7!$ to take care of the permutations. The answer thus, is in fact $7!\binom{26}{7} = 20*21*...*26$.

For b), we go by this logic: We have to choose $6$ letters out of 26: This can be done in $\binom{26}{6}$ ways. Now, we can choose the letter that we are doubling in $6$ ways, $1$ of the $6$ that we have chosen.  Now, note that if we assume that all our letters are distinct, then we have 7! words again, but this time we have to divide by $2$($2!$ to be precise) because,for example, there is no difference between the words $l_1ol_2$ and $l_2ol_1$. They both spell $lol$, because the letters $l_1$ and $l_2$ are the same. Now, we write down the answer as $\frac{6\binom{26}{6} * 7!}{2}$. I'll leave you to find the right expression.

For the third part,we go by this logic: We have to choose $5$ letters out of 26: This can be done in $\binom{26}{5}$ ways. Now, we can choose the letter that we are doubling in $5$ ways, $1$ of the $5$ that we have chosen.  Now, note that if we assume that all our letters are distinct, then we have 7! words again, but this time we have to divide by $6$($3!$ to be precise) because,for example, there is no difference between the words $l_1ol_2l_3$ and $l_2ol_3l_1$. They both spell $loll$, because the letters $l_1,l_2$ and $l_3$ are the same. Now, we write down the answer as $\frac{5\binom{26}{5} * 7!}{6}$. I'll leave you to find the right expression once again.

See the methodical manner in which we approach these problems. You can use your own method ( I know another solution involving filling boxes) to come up  with the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, there exists a problem with your solution.

To understand what you are doing wrong, we should model the amount of permutations for a single word with all distinct letters.

The first letter can be one of $26:$ leaving us with $26$ possibilities. **However**, the second word must not be the same as the first, so it must be one of the $25$ other letters, leaving us with $25$ possibilities. The third word also can't use either of the previous $2$ letters, so it has $24$ letters, leaving us with $24$ possibilities. This continues for all $7$ letters.

The first letter has $26$ possibilities, the second has $25,$ then $24, 23, 22, 21,$ and finally $20$. By using the multiplication rule, we get that the possibilities $p$ for a distinctly lettered word is

$$p = 26 * 25 * 24 * 23 * 22 * 21 * 20 = \frac{26!}{19!}$$

Similarly, with a word with a double, the first and second letters can have 26 possibilities, the third have $25$ and so on. This gives us

$$p = 26 * 25 * 24 * 23 * 22 * 21 = 26\cdot\frac{26!}{20!}$$

We can generalize this for any $n$ letters which are the same if $n >0$

$$p(n)=\frac{26!}{(18+n)!}$$

Which yields

$$p(1)=\frac{26!}{19!} = 3315312000$$
$$p(2)=\frac{26!}{20!} = 165765600$$
$$p(3)=\frac{26!}{21!} = 7893600$$
$$p(4)=\frac{26!}{22!} = 358800$$
$$p(5)=\frac{26!}{23!} = 15600$$
$$p(6)=\frac{26!}{24!} = 650$$
$$p(7)=\frac{26!}{25!} = 26$$